# Call controller function and unset variable in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function getEvent();. This function does what it says. Now i have a function duplicateEvent(). It does what it says too. I want to remove the ID from the scope that getEvent receives. So if i use $scope.event.event.id = null in my duplicateEvent() function, this wont make the event ID null.

```
$scope.getEvent = function ( value )
    {
        eventFactory.getEvent(value)
            .then(function ( response )
            {
                //Reset input field after a new getEvent Request
                angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null);
                $scope.event = response.data;

                $scope.flyers = {
                    front: {
                        preview: $scope.event.event.flyer_front,
                        isNew: false,
                    },
                    back: {
                        preview: $scope.event.event.flyer_back,
                        isNew: false,
                    }
                };

                $('#form-date-start').datetimepicker({
                    value: $filter('formatDate')($scope.event.event.dates.raw.date_start, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')
                });

                $('#form-date-end').datetimepicker({
                    value: $filter('formatDate')($scope.event.event.dates.raw.date_end, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')
                });

            });
    };

$scope.duplicateEvent = function ( id )
{
    $scope.event.event.id = null;
};
```

Comment: Wouter, what did you changed? Got only a message from a change, not a visual

Comment: This question is confusing.  First, it doesn't look like `$scope.duplicateEvent` is actually duplicating anything.  Second, there isn't any code here that would "unset" anything.

Comment: Last line on `duplicateEvent` looks to me like you were expecting `getEvent` to modify `$scope.event` before being printed.

Comment: also, you can't use `$scope.getEvent(id).then`, because `getEvent` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: I changed my code to what i want to achieve... Sorry, im dutch so kinda hard to expain

Comment: so there is only one event on the page, and when you call the `duplicateEvent` function, you want the `event.id` to be erased?

Comment: Yeah exactly. First i get all the events. A user can edit it, or duplicate it. Once he hits duplicate, the scope.event will be updated, the ID will be removed so i can catch it as a new event

Comment: that still doesn't make sense.  Your code doesn't show "all events", it shows a single event.  Also, you can't "duplicate" an object by simply removing it's `id` Property;  As far as JavaScript is concerned, that's still the same object, even without an `id` Property.